# Does the set of all functions $f(x)$ defined on the range $0 < x < 1$ that vanish at $x=0$ and $x=0$ form a vector space? If not, why?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Here's what I need to show.

I have to show that $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and that $(cf)(x) = cf(x)$ for any scalar $c$. I have to show that both addition and multiplication by a scalar is also in the range of $(0,1)$ and that they vanish at $x = 0 $ and $x = 1$.

Since I know that addition and multiplication by a scalar are closed in the set, I just have to show whether $f(x)$ is a vector space or not by saying that $f(x) + g(x)$ might not be defined from $(0,1)$, and may not vanish at $x = 0$ or $x = 1$.

Thus, $f(x)$ is not a vector space? I think I know how to tackle the problem, but I need some reassurance of whether I am correct for the right reasons or not.

Comment: What leads you to think that this space, call it $\mathscr F$, is not a vector space?  Can you find examples where $f,g\in \mathscr F$ but $f+g \;or\;cf\; \notin \mathscr F$

Comment: I can't think of any real specific ones at the top of my head. I thought that adding functions together might kick the function out of definition from (0,1), which does not make that a vector space.

Comment: Well, if $x\in [0,1]$ then $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ so if $f,g$ are both defined at $x$ then so is their sum.  Similarly, if $f,g$ vanish at the endpoints then so does their sum (note: it would be different if you required some other specific value at the endpoints).

Comment: Oh, I see. I was just assuming that $(c(f+g))(x) = cf(x) + cg(x)$ is indeed closed, but I forgot to realize that there is closure also at the boundaries in which each is defined. In other words $f(x)$ is not just closed under addition and scalar multiplication, it is also closed at the boundaries in which it is defined.

Comment: I think it's confusing to refer to the space as $f(x)$.  That looks more like an element of the space.  But, yes.  The space in question is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.